# Find which distrubtion a RPM belongs to ? RHEL or Centos or Suse

Tags: unix, rpm, rhel

How do I find to which distribution (for example, RHEL or Centos or Suse) a RPM file belongs to?

I have a RHEL box, can I use RPM provided at link, https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/libRmath.html

Comment: Downvote without a reason ? Would have appreciated if  downVoter would have questioned before doing so .

Comment: Your original question was a bit confusing. Hopefully the edit above clarifies.

Comment: To answer the other question you may want to ask it separately. But generally, you can install packages from other distributions but they may not work since the libraries and package install locations may differ.

Comment: @Adam B So in that case you can set your library path to make them work , right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can determine the original package source for an RPM. The RPM header has a wealth of information about the package, including the Vendor and Packager.

To view the information on a package, use the `rpm` command as follows:

```
rpm -q -i -p libRmath-3.2.3-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

`-q` means to query the RPM file

`-i` prints out the information contained in the RPM header

`-p` Points RPM to the file to query. You can also pass it a URL if desired.

For the package you mentioned, here is the output of the above command:

```
warning: libRmath-3.2.3-4.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
Name        : libRmath
Version     : 3.2.3
Release     : 4.el6
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Development/Libraries
Size        : 242971
License     : GPLv2+
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Wed 27 Jan 2016 01:29:08 PM PST, Key ID 3b49df2a0608b895
Source RPM  : R-3.2.3-4.el6.src.rpm
Build Date  : Tue 26 Jan 2016 02:22:41 PM PST
Build Host  : buildvm-26.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Fedora Project
Vendor      : Fedora Project
URL         : http://www.r-project.org
Summary     : Standalone math library from the R project
Description :
A standalone library of mathematical and statistical functions derived
from the R project.  This package provides the shared libRmath library.
```

Whether or not the RPM is compatible with the system you are trying to install it on is a different issue. You can either do it by testing or stick with a distribution you know to have a similar set of libraries as your target system.